# React Native - Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-emulator

I connected my Android Device to My MacBook, 
Opened my react-native project, 
and did:

> adb devices

And I was able to see my connected device. Then I did:

> react-native run-android

And got the following error:

```
Prasangs-MBP:myScheduler prasang$ react-native run-android
Scanning 640 folders for symlinks in 
/Users/prasang/RNProjects/myScheduler/node_modules (6ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp3101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0472Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE   
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningDebug
:app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'iBall Slide Twinkle i5 - 5.1' for     app:debug
08:27:51 E/1273203309: Error while uploading app-debug.apk : Unknown failure ([CDS]close[0])
Unable to install /Users/prasang/RNProjects/myScheduler/android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to install all 
    at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:89)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:904)
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:137)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.InstallVariantTask.install(InstallVariantTask.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:228)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:621)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:604)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:239)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:212)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:205)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
:app:installDebug FAILED    

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: 
  com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to install all
```

My Device: iBall Slide Twinkle i5 - Android 5.1

PS:

1. The app is working well in iOS simulator.
2. The app is also working well on my other Android device (OnePlus 2 - v6.0.1) as well.
3. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171712/blu-r1-hd-phone-android-failed-to-install-unknown-failure-cdsclose0) answer is focused on Android v6.0, and so it is not the answer to this question.

Comment: Please add the full error message. Above the `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.` there must be a second error message.

Comment: @bennygenel I've added the full error message now.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39191388/2315280) answer.,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blu R1 HD Phone - Android Failed to install: Unknown failure (\[CDS\]close\[0\])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171712/blu-r1-hd-phone-android-failed-to-install-unknown-failure-cdsclose0)

Comment: @bennygenel Nope. It's different.

Comment: @bennygenel Nope. Not same. Also, my device is not using v6.0 Marshmallow. It's on 5.1 (as mentioned in the question).

Comment: different how? You have the same error with the other question. have you tried the solution?

Comment: @bennygenel because I'm trying to run the app on Android v5.1 Device (Not v6.0).

Comment: @bennygenel Also, my minSdkVersion= 16 and targetSdkVersion= 22, already.

Answer (score 0):

Check JDK is installed in your machine or not ,for me installing jdk solved the problem.